# Sending function pointer over network in python

Tags: python, function, networking, pointers, distributed

Is there a possibility to send a function pointer in python over network to run on another machine?

let's say I have a function that I want to run:

```
def myFunc():
  ...
```

Is it possible to send myFunc to another machine by using function pointers, or is the function pointer only locally available?
If that is not possible, what other options do I have? Sending python files?

I'm not interested about how networking works in python, because that part is already fully implemented.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/

Comment: Yum, remote code execution. Hope you are really truly securing your connections. Assuming this is true though, +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider to pickle your function and send it over network?

EXAMPLE (SERVER):

```
import pickle

def test1():        #Function to be send
    return True


with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:    #On server you pickling function
    pickle.dump(test1.__code__, f)
```

EXAMPLE (CLIENT):

```
import pickle
import types

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:    #On client you load and unpickle function
    code = pickle.load(f)

test2 = types.FunctionType(code, globals())


print(test2())    #Result will be True
```

NOTE: Be aware about security issues that can arise when sending code over network.

Comment: But as far as I know Classes, functions, and methods can not be pickled!

Comment: This doesn't work. It pickles a reference to the function, but that function must be on the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy out of the box. You need the .py file on the remote machine. But you can do it with [Python fabric](http://fabfile.org).

Comment: I think I was a little bit unclear, but I wont run "commands", I want to run my python function (i.e. an algorithm) on another computer, how do I send the function? It seems that "fabric" is like "remote system administration"...

Comment: @ux11 you can send functions you define in a fab file to other machines. They can be used for system administration or other purposes.